# Xcode 4 - How to enter input into Debugger

Tags: python, debugging, xcode4

I am running Python in Xcode 4, and I need to enter some input into the Debugger. How do I do that?

Comment: kinda... i am trying to use raw_input() here. I can put my cursor in there, but I can't type like in Terminal